# symfony2 collection select entity

Tags: symfony, collections, entity

have this ..

```
$builder->add('city', 'entity', array(
                'class' => '..\Entity\City',
                'translation_domain' => $this->translation_domain,
                'required' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'invalid_message' => 'form.error.city',
                'empty_value' => 'form.placeholder.city',
                'query_builder' => function (...\Repository\CityRepository $repository) {
                    return $repository->get(array(
                        'enabled' => true,
                        'locale' => $this->container->get('poisk_raboty.helper.main')->getLocale(),
                    ), true);
                },
                'attr' => array(
                    'data-search' => 2,
                    'data-placeholder' => $this->container->get('translator')->trans('form.placeholder.city', array(), $this->translation_domain),
                ),
            ))
        ;
```

How can I get cities in form builder, where one element must be like city?

Comment: Please describe your problem, do you have an error? What is being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

```
        ->add('cities', 'collection', array(
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'type' => 'entity',
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'PoiskRaboty\MainBundle\Entity\City',
                'translation_domain' => $this->translation_domain,
                'invalid_message' => 'form.error.city',
                'property' => 'title',
                'expanded' => true,
                'empty_value' => 'form.placeholder.city',
                'query_builder' => function (\PoiskRaboty\MainBundle\Repository\CityRepository $repository) {
                    return $repository->get(array(
                        'enabled' => true,
                        'locale' => $this->container->get('poisk_raboty.helper.main')->getLocale(),
                    ), true);
                },
                'attr' => array(
                    'data-search' => 2,
                    'data-placeholder' => $this->container->get('translator')->trans('form.placeholder.city', array(), $this->translation_domain),
                ),
            ]
        ))
```